# how can I add a parameter as dynamic array to the function in php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

```
$updateRoles=array();
 $updateRoles["role_name"]="Manager";
 $updateRoles["role_description"]="Manages system";
 $whereRoles["roleid"]=15;
 $sdb->dbUpdate("user_roles",$updateRoles,$whereRoles);
```

Look at the sample. I got this code snippet from a library. I'm curious, How can I code
dbUpdate function ? Because this function has dynamic parameters. Can you show me a sample regarding functions with dynamic array parameters?

Comment: What is dynamic with that? Its passing 2 arrays as second and third parameter...

Comment: Yes How can I write this function ? I need sample...

Comment: it's simple like any other method: `public function dbUpdate($string, $arr1, $arr2){...}` - It seems like you expecting some magic behind this - there isn't any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Solution:

```
function BilgiEkle ($tablo,$data) 

     {  
        $tablo = trim($tablo);
        $str = "(";
        $str2 = "(";    
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $str = $str . '`' . $key . '`' . ','; 
            $str2 = $str2 ."'". $value  ."'". ',';
        }
        $str = substr($str, 0, -1);
        $str2 = substr($str2, 0, -1);
        $str = $str . ")";
        $str2 = $str2 . ")";




        $sqlifade = "INSERT INTO `$tablo` $str VALUES $str2 ";



        $islem=$this->baglan->prepare($sqlifade);
        $islem->execute();

        return $islem->rowCount();
    }
```

Ex:

```
$arr=array();
$arr['name']='burhan';
$arr['familyname']='tanis';
bilgiEkle('table1',$arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at func_num_args(), func_get_arg() and func_get_args().

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php